# How to save values into Edittext?

Tags: java, android

I have created source and destination as a two edit-text in which i am placing the source and destination address from another activity but the first or second value is removed when coming back for placing second value. When first value is placed into first edit-text and going to place another value from another activity the first value is removed.

I have tried the Sharedpreferences but it is not working well any idea for this.

Here is my code.

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String source = intent.getStringExtra("place");
    search.setText(source);
    Intent intent1 = getIntent();
    String dest = intent1.getStringExtra("my1dest");
    desti.setText(dest);


    swap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String s1 = search.getText().toString();
            String s2 = desti.getText().toString();
            if (!s1.isEmpty() && !s2.isEmpty()) {
                desti.setText(s1);
                search.setText(s2);// this for swap the values source to destination viceversa



            }

        }
    });
```

and from this adpter class i am passing the values

```
  Intent intent=new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);

            intent.putExtra("place",searchlist.getPlaces());
            intent.putExtra("dest",searchlist.getPlaces());
            intent.putExtra("lat",searchlist.getLat());
            intent.putExtra("lang",searchlist.getLang());
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            context.startActivity(intent);
```

please give idea for this concept thank you..

[see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bymlZ.png)

Comment: I am getting problem like this please see this video link in which when i am selecting second value the first edit-text is changing see this link [Video-link](https://webrooper.com/video/demo.mp4)  i am using sharedprefrences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to save values that are passed from two different activities than you should have a mechanism to save the first value and then should get other value from another activity.

The issue is that you are replacing the values with the same intent (intent from same activity):

```
Intent intent = getIntent();  //if this is intent from your MainActivity
String source = intent.getStringExtra("place");  //you will get this value
search.setText(source);
Intent intent1 = getIntent(); //and this as well is intent from same activity (MainActivity)
String dest = intent1.getStringExtra("my1dest"); //you will not get this value as this is not passed from MainActivity
desti.setText(dest);
```

The solution could be saving one value to SharedPreference or any other mean(db or network) and get other value from other intent: you should check if the value is null then don't replace it. 
Like :

```
Intent intent = getIntent();  //if this is intent from your MainActivity
String source = intent.getStringExtra("place");  //you will get this value
if(source.isNotEmpty){
//save to preferences and set text 
search.setText(source);
}

Intent intent1 = getIntent(); //if this is intent from your otherActivity 
String dest = intent1.getStringExtra("my1dest"); 
if(dest.isNotEmpty){
//save to preferences and set text 
desti.setText(dest);
}
```

Comment: I am adding the both values from another activity

Comment: please see this video link is here [Video-link](https://webrooper.com/video/demo.mp4)

Comment: I think you can achieve this by calling 'startActivityForResult' and then get results on 'onActivityResult' but still, you should save your data after returning back to the activity.

Comment: Sir in my case there is no need to save data using sharedprefrence its working for me without any saving data using onActivityResult

Comment: Sir can you please help me?. I want to show recyclerview after the source and destination is set using geofire sir please any help for me [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61663987/how-to-display-specific-recyclerview-using-geofire)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code

```
Edittext source,destination;
    swap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String s1 = search.getText().toString();
            String s2 = desti.getText().toString();

            if (s1.contains(s1) && s2.contains(s2)) {
                desti.setText(s1);
                search.setText(s2);
            } else {
                desti.setText(s2);
                search.setText(s1);
            }


        }
    });//for setting values from one edittext to another


    search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Added.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent,1);
        }
    });

    desti.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Destinationsearch.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent,2);
        }
    });// here i have started Activity For result to my Adapter class
```

getting  values from Adapter class

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null)
    {
        String place=data.getStringExtra("place");
        search.setText(place);

    }

    if (requestCode==2 && resultCode==RESULT_OK && data!=null)
    {
        String dest=data.getStringExtra("my1dest");
        desti.setText(dest);
    }
}
```

and this is my Adpter class

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull SearchedAdapter.Myholder holder, int position) {
    Searchlist searchlist = list.get(position);

    holder.textView.setText(searchlist.getPlaces());

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("place", searchlist.getPlaces());
            intent.putExtra("my1dest", searchlist.getPlaces());
            intent.putExtra("lat", searchlist.getLat());
            intent.putExtra("lang", searchlist.getLang());
            ((Activity) context).setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
            ((Activity) context).finish();
        }
    });

}
```

That set (: